# How to get the property name from default setter name?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I am trying to figure out the original property name from the setter selector. For example I know that the setter is called `setFoo:` and would like to get `foo`. It should be a quite easy string processing task (remove `set` and change the first letter to lowercase) but I was wondering if there are any out of the box solution somewhere in the Objective-C runtime.

I would like to use it like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL foo;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@dynamic foo;

+(BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)sel
{
    const char* selectorName = sel_getName(sel);
    objc_property_t getterProperty = class_getProperty([self class], selectorName);
    objc_property_t setterProperty = class_getProperty([self class], getPropertyNameFromSetterName(selectorName));
    if (getterProperty) {
        // now I know that the property was declared and I should provide
        // the getter implementation
    } else if (setterProperty) {
        // I should provide the setter implementation
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can also override the default name (normally done with `BOOL` getter methods to provide the `isThing` version) so your logic may not work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're right, I'll have to enumerate all properties returned by `class_copyPropertyList` and compare my selector to the last attribute of the properties returned by `property_getAttributes`. Unfortunately it seems this later returns only the property setter name only if it is not the default one so I would still need `getPropertyNameFromSetterName`.

Comment: Also , keep in mind that the first letter of the property can also be uppercase. I know it's not standard but it can be. So I think you should : remove 'set' , check if the object responds to the lowercase getter and if not , make the first letter uppercase and check if the object responds to that one.